# Execute Commands in Kali-Linux's Terminal through Python

Tags: python, kali-linux

I want to execute commands in the terminal through a python scripts.

i want to create a script which takes data from a .txt file adds that in a list and then one by one execute them in the terminal.

what i am looking for is a process to execute commands in the  terminal in Kali Linux, I couldn't find anything online.

like in windows we use `import subprocess` or `import os`

Thank you.

example command is like

```
python3 app.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import subprocess
command = "python3 app.py"
subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `os.system` function.  It returns the return value of the command run.

E.g.,

```
status = os.system('echo hello')
```

Comment: i would like to run a script like ```python3 app.py ```

Comment: `os.system('python3 app.py')`